# Is it ok to ask something on SO which has been already asked unsuccessfully on SU?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

The question is not directly related to programming, but I assume the question is useful for programmers, too. Also it is complex and better understood around programmers than super users.

SU lacks a good base for now.

Comment: It would help if you linked the question

Comment: Are you asking about a hacker's favourite OS?

Comment: @random. Third time lucky? I hope not.

Comment: RE: better understood around programmers than "users". These weren't just *users*, they were *Superusers*

Answer (score 8):

**No**

Unless the question has been closed, it would be ideal to improve the question by editing it with more information. If all else fails there is also the option of adding a bounty.

If the question is related to programming, flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated, and the moderators will review the request.

Don't repost questions, they can be migrated and this ensures they are not closed as duplicates.